# mutate resampling (rset) object

Tags: resampling, tidymodels

I have created resampling folds using `vfold_cv()`. I need to adjust the `$data` dataframes within the `$splits` in each fold. After doing this, however, the object is no longer a `rset` object. How can I adjust the dataframes within each fold and keep the `rset` attribute please? Note that the adjustment can only be done within the folds, not prior to splitting.

Comment: So we have certain rules about what defines specific types of resampling objects. One of them is, if you change the underlying data, you’re not the same object, as you were before. Same thing with deleting rows. If you are a 10-fold cross-validation object, but only have five rows, you can’t be that type of object.

Comment: Can you describe why you would need to alter the data after creating the object?

Comment: @topepo Because I need to score the observations in each of the training sets independent of the test sets. If I score the whole lot prior to splitting into folds then there will be data leakage.